# dataview doesnt sort correct

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I'm trying to add my dataView list to my datagrid and it should be sorted DESC but for some reason it doesnt sort correct.

for now i can only see my result's but not sorted DESC.

```
XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new XmlDataDocument();
xmlDatadoc.DataSet.ReadXml("D:\\score.xml");
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Score data");
ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;
DataView myDataView = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
myDataView.Sort = "score DESC";
dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataView;
```

This is what i should get:

```
101
100
99
98
```

But this i what it shows:

```
99
98
101
100
```

Comment: Order the DataTable :             DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<int>("score DESC")).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: thx for the reply but unfortunately it gave me the same results

Comment: The data must be strings and not numbers.  The sort is comparing 1 against 9 and not 99 against 101.  Try using Parse() to fix issue : dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Field<string>("score DESC"))).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: You'll have a better example if you add "10" to your data. Now it's not easy to spot it's string sorting (=alphabetical order) and not numbers

Answer (score 1):

So eventually i tried something different and i loaded in the xml file and selected the child note that i wanted to sort and converted in to a int than sort the xmlFile save the sorted xml file and than i loaded it in my datagridView the correct way.

```
  public void xmlSort()
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Load("D:\\score.xml");
        XElement[] sortedTables = root.Elements("xmlScore").OrderByDescending(t => (int)t.Element("score")).ToArray();
        root.ReplaceAll(sortedTables);
        root.Save("D:\\score.xml");
    }

 public void readXml()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\score.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        ls = (List<xmlScore>)xs.Deserialize(fs);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ls;
        fs.Close();
    }
```